# -lglut32 cannot be found

Tags: c++, dll, header

I run my project which uses:

```
#include <C:\Users\R\Desktop\LABO3\zad3\Debug\glut.h>
```

but then when I build it I get this error:

```
--------------------Configuration: zad3 - Release--------------------
Linking...
C:\Program Files (x86)\MinGWStudio\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lglut32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

zad3.exe - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

How to fix this? I got the dll in the projects directory.

Comment: Ugh; absolute paths in `#include`? Really?!

Comment: I would not recommend using mingw developer studio since that ide is very incomplete and it's missing some very basic and important diagnostic features to aid in debugging. eg. it has no way to even show what commands it used to build your project. This makes it neigh impossible to debug build problems.

Comment: Build your program from the command line. Something like `g++ -Wall -pedantic -O0 -g example.cpp -o example.exe -L. -lglut32` should do the trick. I'd also suggest checking out [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) instead simply because it's still actively maintained unlike glut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the dll in the projects directory.

Then you need to provide `-L.` on the compilation command line.

Otherwise the DLL should be in some system directory that's on the `PATH`.

Compilers generally expect libraries to be system-installed and available from anywhere on that system, rather than in some specific project's directory.

Comment: What is system directory for Windows 8.1?

Comment: @Yoda: Now your question is _completely_ different. Please don't do that. (a) Write a new question for your new problem, (b) only after you've spent more than two minutes trying to figure it out on your own. Thanks.